# ListBox Items isEnabled WP7

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-phone-7

I am trying to set the isEnabled property to false for a ListBox Item. Included in the code is a some xaml that shows how it is done in the designer, but I need to do it in code.

Here is my code:

```
string[] names = { "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta" };

        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(names[i].ToString());

            //set items 2 & 4 to isEnabled=false
             //   <ListBoxItem Content="beta" IsEnabled="False" />  xaml code

            // My Attempt, does not compile, cannot be used like a method
            // listBox1.isEnabled(2,false);  


        }
```

This is for a WindowsPhone7 app using C#/Silverlight.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
 listBox1.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = "one", IsEnabled = true });
 listBox1.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = "two", IsEnabled = false});
```

Then when you want to get the selected item you can do

```
  void listbox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
       ListBoxItem selectedItem = listbox1.SelectedItem;
       stirng content = selectedItem.Content.ToString()
  }
```

Comment: gabnfill, That adds the items to the ListBox, but now when I press the link, my Selection_Changed event does not have the string as an "e" argument. The value in the e.AddedItmes[0].ToString() was "alpha".  any ideas?

Comment: @TreyBalut get the selected item, cast to ListBoxItem. get the Content, cast to string

Answer (score -1):

IF you want to set it for the third item for example:

```
listBox1.Items[2].IsEnabled = false;
```

Comment: I'm getting an object has no definition for the "IsEnabled" property.